If block is being executed but not printing the given output where else is working properly
I have a if and else block in which if block is checking for presence of winner and printing something and even after successful executing of if winner.present? its not printing the statement where else block is working properly.
Here is the code:
<% if game.finished? %> 
  <center>
    <% if game.winner.present? %>
      <%debugger%>
      It's a win!  // This line is not being printed on execution
    <% else %>
      It's a draw!
      <%= link_to 'Back', root_path %>
    <% end %>
  </center>
<% else %>
<% end %>

I tried different syntax for printing puts span tag and changing the if loop with unless and switching statements and still its not working.

so in the view It's a win! is not printed and It's a draw! is printed?

Exactly that is what I am confused about that why its happening ?
Like when winner is present it should write It's a win but its not doing that even after successful execution and condition is also true but when else block is true its printing the desired statement this is the issue

maybe <%debugger%> is reason?

It's just for debugging. I have tried removing it but still not working

It returns the symbol of winner player

Just to clarify: if game.winner.present? is true, does it print nothing or does it print "It's a draw!" instead?

If game.winner.present? it should print Its a win and done end of the loop and if not then it should go to else block and print It's a draw
But the issue is when game.winner.present is true then its not printing It's a win even after execution but its printing the else block successfully

"when game.winner.present is true then its not printing" – at the HTML level, does it generate an empty <center> tag or nothing at all?

It generates nothing I have tried putting the back link in winner.present block also but its still doesnt shows anything cant understand why its happening

"It generates nothing" – does game.finished? return true? (the very first line / condition)

if game.winner.present? is very smelly. present? is really just for checking for input. I would create  draw? and winner? methods in the Game model instead of making the view too aware the internals of the models.

You could add some winner is: <%= game.winner %> in your code to see if the actual value of that is making it to your view. You don't show any backend code of how you get game or winner so it's really just guessing at this point.
